# Regular expressions in Google Analytics

Tags: regex

I have the pages that I want to set as a goal in Google Analytics but there is a part of the URL that is dynamic number (3 integers). How do I specify such a URL with regex?

URLs are:

```
/info.php?id=XXX&sent=ok
```

I am using this regular expression

```
/info.php?id=^[0-9]{3}$&sent=ok
```

But it is not working.

What is wrong?

Comment: @RichB: how's this not a beginner question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `^` and `$` parts. They refer to the beginning and ending of the string, and you have them right in the middle, so nothing can possibly match that expression.

Also the `?` symbol is a reserved operator in regular expressions. It means the preceding item is optional. You'll want to escape it by replacing it with `\?`.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape any regex reserved characters like `?`.  also the `$` is usually a line ending in regex, as well as `^` being a line beginning, so yours would fail.  Something closer to :

```
/info\.php\?id=[0-9]{3}&sent=ok
```

might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

you're using `^` and `$` which match beginning and end of the line, respectively. this should work:

```
/info\.php\?id=[0-9]{3}&sent=ok
```